# Chrome for macOS shows raw HTML for gmail.com

Tags: google-chrome

I posted this question in the google communities forum [here](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AFnwnKVLRoT7D9BXGHhBLgVJMdwKOG8WzG2rv-vwrScojmwZRdaC2FuGJ7ONoCR5rZ6kAKofg7JWLF6KCyi5C_aRww-yXjbm8IXg4svjSTnjthgAvJxoEbYssQxKN1Q) but did not receive a response so I thought I'd ask here. I'm not sure if it's specific to apple but I thought it could be worth a shot trying this here first, over stack overflow.

When I visit gmail, Chrome doesn't render the HTML but just displays it raw, similar to if I had right-clicked and then regular clicked `View Page Source`. And it's just the source code and not an working HTML-only render.

Visiting the same URL with a different browser, on the same machine with the same OS, does render the HTML in the typical fashion.

How can I get Chrome to render the HTML rather than just print it out?

I've tried resetting Chrome to default settings, and uninstalling and re-installing Chrome. The problem still persists. I did just upgrade to Mojave but Chrome worked normally after the upgrade for awhile before it started behaving strangely.

Shot of how it appears.
[image: screnshot]

Comment: Hey Mote - that's definitely an interesting issue. Could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing? I know, just the HTML code, but the way it's being presented could give a clue.

Comment: @MikeyT.K. Added Screen shot of output

Comment: Can you try an older version of chrome ? It may come with some other problems.. one being only third party sites offering the old packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved thanks to a solution posted in the Google forum. It was solved but hitting `command-shift-R`. I have no idea why.

[Link](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/16593185?hl=en) to forum post.