# iCloud email attachments not opening on HP computer running Win10

Tags: icloud, email, attachments

I have a new HP computer running Windows 10. Each time I go to open an attachment through my iCloud email, the attachments come up with codes instead of their content.

How do I fix this so that I can actually see and print the attachments?

**Note:** I'm not all that computer savvy.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Apple.SE! Does this happen for all mail services or just iCloud mail? If others too show this behaviour, it might make it off-topic, it being a windows specific problem. https://superuser.com might be a better fit then. If it's just iCloud, can you tell which format attachments are showing up as code?

Comment: If you're using chrome, [Chrome for macOS shows raw HTML for gmail.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372410/chrome-for-macos-shows-raw-html-for-gmail-com) is a similar question with no answers yet. (Notify me by @ankii)

Comment: Hi! It only happens with my iCloud. My gmail works fine. What do you mean by format attachments? Is that what the sender has used to send the attachments through? I can get on my computer tomorrow and take photos of the codes that pop up to show you?

Comment: I meant, is it images, pdfs, or something else? Yeah, no issues with tomorrow, just ping me using @ in case someone else comments. The code is most probably HTML as I linked in second comment and I don't think I'll be of much help there. Try different browser: Edge or Firefox.